# RoR : delayed job not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want the execution of a method in a controller to run in background, so that the speed is not affected. I found out that this could be done using delayed jobs.

following is the method I want to delay:

```
private
    def update_product_count(skus, qty)
      path = File.expand_path('../../../voylla_scripts/eBay', __FILE__)
      system "python2 "+path+"/ReviseOnOrder.py #{skus.to_json} #{qty.to_json} #{path}> output"
    end
```

I tried using:

```
def show
    if defined? Delayed::Job
        Delayed::Job.enqueue(update_product_count(@skus.to_s, @qty.to_s))
    end
end
```

This runs the script within the delayed method, but gives error:

```
ArgumentError in OrdersController#show
Cannot enqueue items which do not respond to perform
```

and the view corresponding to the `show` does not get rendered.

then I tried:

```
def show
    delay.update_product_count(@skus.to_s, @qty.to_s)
end
```

This doesn't run the method and also gives the following error:

```
ArgumentError in OrdersController#show
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

I also tried `handle_asynchronously :update_product_count`. But this too gives `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

Could someone please help me figure this out. Thanks

**EDIT:** the following change does not give any error, but the script does seem to run

/lib/update_count.rb

```
class UpdateCount < Struct.new(:skus, :qty, :path)
    def perform
        system "python2 "+path+"/ReviseOnOrder.py #{skus.to_json} #{qty.to_json} #{path}"
    end
end
```

/app/controller/order_controller.rb:

```
require 'update_count'
def show
   Delayed::Job.enqueue(UpdateCount.new(@skus.to_s, @qty.to_s, path))
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda embarrassing:

```
script/delayed_job start.
```

phew!!

Answer (score 1):

Place the code you want to execute in perform method, and enqueu the class in the delayed jobs, which when executed will call the perform method

Eg:

/lib/product_count.rb

```
class ProductCount < Struct.new(:skus, :qty)
  def perform
    path = File.expand_path('../../../voylla_scripts/eBay', __FILE__)
    system "python2 "+path+"/ReviseOnOrder.py #{skus.to_json} #{qty.to_json} #{path}> output"

  end
end
```

Call the delayed job

> > Delayed::Job.enqueue(ProductCount.new(@skus.to_s, @qty.to_s), :queue => "product_count")

Comment: Could you please explain, whats different here except for the path?

Comment: I did this, and added `debugger` in the perform method. But I dont hit the debug mode. It seems the execution does not reach there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new class with public method "perform" which will incapsulate all job that you want:

```
class MegaJob
  def initialize(options=nil)
    @skus = options[:skus]
    @qty =  options[:qty]
  end

  def perform
    update_product_count
  end

  private

  def update_product_count
    path = File.expand_path('../../../voylla_scripts/eBay', __FILE__)
    system "python2 "+path+"/ReviseOnOrder.py #{@skus.to_json} #{@qty.to_json} #{path}> output"
  end
end
```

To start this job:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue MegaJob.new(skus: your_skus, qty: your_qty)
```

PS Don`t copy and paste the example!

Comment: This gives me `uninitialized constant OrdersController::UpdateCount`. I created the class in lib folder.

Comment: I think, that you try to use an action from controller in class **MegaJob** - its really wrong way!. Try to do something easily at beginning in `perform` method, like `File.open('tmp/asd.txt', 'w') { |f| f.write 'Hello from delayed job!' }` аnd check the file in tmp folder after start the job!

Comment: I guess I'm not doing that. I have updated the question with the details.. There are no errors but I think the delayed job didn't run, the python script did not perform the task it was supposed to

Comment: I have edited my answer) Actually, I don`t know why the python script did not run, it may be caused by many reasons like wrong path or something like that.